# Google App Engine - Google APIs Console - Google Cloud Console

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api-console, google-cloud-console

I wanted to ask what the difference between Google App Engine, Google APIs Console and Google Cloud Console is?

I will deploy a Project which will fetch some Websites and provide the data to my Android Application.

What is the best to use? I do not know what is for what.

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine lets you run web applications on Google's infrastructure : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine

Google APIs Console is Console to administrate Google API (deprecated)

Google Cloud Console is new version of Google APIs Console.

So for your Project use Google App Engine.
And for example use URL Fetch https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/

Answer (score 0):

A bit of background: At one point in time, Google APIs had its own console and Google App Engine had its own console. Eventually, it was decided that we should merge these two consoles into one console. We've already turned down the APIs console, and we're working on turning down the App Engine admin console.

So to answer your question: you should use the Cloud console unless you need to use the App Engine admin console for some obscure reason.

[image]